# What am I doing wrong with tensorflow serving with docker?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to do tensorflow serving with REST API using docker. I was following example from  https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker, and https://towardsdatascience.com/serving-keras-models-locally-using-tensorflow-serving-tf-2-x-8bb8474c304e. I've created a simple digit mnist classifier. My model's export path:

```
MODEL_DIR = 'digit_mnist/model_serving/'
version = 1
export_path = os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, str(version))
```

then saved model with this command:

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(model,
                           export_path,
                           overwrite=True,
                           include_optimizer=True,
                           save_format=None,
                           signatures=None,
                           options=None)
```

when I run:

```
 sudo docker run -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=/artificial-neural-network/tensorflow_nn/digit_mnist/model_serving/1/,target=/models/model_serving -e MODEL_NAME=dmc -t tensorflow/serving
```

I get this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /artificial-neural-networks/tensorflow_nn/digit_mnist/model_serving/1/.
```

My file structure goes like this:

```
(venv) artificial_neural_networks/
    __init__.py
    pytorch_nn/
    tensorflow_nn/
        __init__.py
        digit_mnist/
            model_serving/
                1/
                    assets
                    variables/
                        variables.data-00000-of-00002
                        variables.data-00001-of-00002
                        variables.index
                    saved_model.pb
            __init__.py
            mnist.py
```

Where am I doing the wrong thing? I'm on my second day of solving this problem so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `artificial-neural-networks` directory located at the root of your linux directory tree (`/`) on the host? The error clearly states the bind source path does not exists.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add that this is virtual env, but I tried the same thing without virtual env, and I specified path from my root directory but it didn't work.

Comment: running in a virtualenv does not change your directory tree root. You still need to give the full path to your bind mount source to docker anyway. `didn't work` is not an accurate description of your problem. Same error => there is still a problem with your bind mount source path. Different => we would need to know to tell.

Comment: when I run from root I get this 'error: docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint zen_feynman (8f3d2374f49c3eac1ea7e5a0dcf5891253920d6e4bcbf017a683c6697ae): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8501 failed: port is already allocated.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled '

Comment: As well I have a question do I need to specify version in my path?

Comment: Please don't add additional info in comments: edit your question instead.Your second error has nothing to do with the bind mound which is now ok. The port 8501 is already in use on your host. Either stop the process using it or choose an other one.

Comment: @ArturasDruteika, Is your issue resolved now? If not, Couple of observations: 

1. `&` is missing at the end of the `docker run command`

2. As suggested by Zeitounator, it is clearly an issue with `Path`. Print your "Present Working Directory" using the command, `pwd`. Share your `docker run command` with the `complete/absolute path`.

Comment: @ArturasDruteika, To resolve the error, `docker: Error response from daemon ... port is already allocated`, 

1. We should execute the command, sudo docker ps -a and should see which Docker Containers are holding the ports.
2. Copy the container ID from the above list
3. Run the Command, sudo docker kill f1db7891a203(this is Container ID)